# How to redirect from blog.example.org to example.com using htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

I have tried all means to do a 301 redirect from `blog.example.org` to `https://www.example.com/post` using `.htaccess` but the redirect doesn't seem to be working.

I'm using this code below;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/post$1 [L,R=301]
```

Kindly someone share with me what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: You've stated you want to redirect from `blog.example.org`, yet you are trying to match this with the regex `^blog/(.*)$`? Do you have a `/blog` subdirectory? Your problem description suggests are are wanting to redirect a single URL to another single URL, however, your code implies a multi-URL to multi-URL redirect from a subdirectory? Please clarify. (Also, test with 302 redirects to avoid caching issues during testing.)

Comment: Do the two hosts `blog.example.org` and `www.example.com` point to the same filesystem, or different?

Answer (score 2):

To change a sub-domain, I use the `ServerAlias` and a condition against the `HTTP_HOST`.

For example, I generally wanted to have "", "w", "ww", "wwww" redirect to "www". I do this using the following type of rules:

```
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com w.example.com ww.example.com wwww.example.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example.com|w.example.com|ww.example.com|wwww.example.com)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

So you could also change a `blog.example.com` to a `www.example.com`. If you prefer to not have any sub-domain, then you can use (see the `blog.example.com`?):

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias w.example.com ww.example.com www.example.com wwww.example.com blog.example.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(w.example.com|ww.example.com|www.example.com|wwww.example.com|blog.example.com)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Note that in Apache2 you could also write two entries to avoid the `RewriteCond`. For example, a `<VirtualHost>` that looks like this:

```
ServerName w.example.com
ServerAlias ww.example.com www.example.com wwww.example.com blog.example.com
```

would not match `example.com` so you do not need to have the `RewriteCond` since you want to redirect all sub-domain to `example.com`.

This does not work in an `.htaccess` file, though since that's already past the `<VirtualHost>` point which is too late.

*Note: answered as per your question, although as MrWhite says, you're not 100% clear about what fails on your end.*